# Why ideavim works diffrently with vim for taglist?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, pycharm, ideavim

In vim, I usually found declaration by taglist using C-]. When I wanted to go back, I hit the C-T for previous location.

I understand it can be done internally by push and pop tag stack. However, in ideavim C-T seems to be strange. I found in ideavim, C-T is to go back not only to tag stack location but also jump stack list.

It's so annoying for me to go back unwanted location. How can I achieve normal workflow for tag in ideavim?

Comment: You have a question in your title which is very different than the question in the body. The answer to "why" is because PyCharm does not implement vim. PyCharm implements enough features of vim to say it has a vim mode and try to entice vim users over. That being said, I'm a die hard vim guy who really enjoys developing in PyCharm. I've accepted that jumping around how I do in vim doesn't always take me where I expect. When it doesn't I then use PyCharm's navigation shortcuts. I don't know the answer to your second question.

Comment: I understand the reason ideavim does not work as my expectation is that it's merely not vim. Maybe I did not choose the right word 'why' though, but as I read help index for ideavim, there were tag list features so I wonder what I was missed. So, your point is to achieve what I want, find the native approch in PyCharm? Is there any alternatives for taglist?

Comment: I think it's a fair question, and I'd like to see if anyone else has ideas on how to improve it (why I upvoted). If I had things setup as you describe I would be happier. I'm not saying you have to or should do anything. It seemed you might be new to PyCharm (your stack overflow account is new, so not sure your familiarity), so I was trying to provide some perspective from a vim user who migrated to PyCharm. I had to give up some of my vim lifestyle, but there were enough goodies in PyCharm to make it worth while for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdeaVim doesn't emulate the tag stack (yet). Instead, it utilizes IntelliJ's "Navigate | Declaration" action for `CTRL-]` and it invokes "Navigate | Forward / Back" on `CTRL-I` / `CTRL-O`.

IdeaVim currently treats `CTRL-T` just like an alias for `CTRL-O`, so you don't have any real tag stack, see [this nasty TODO item](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/0bf561e326bdddbe8f8e1827a0a6c453e359cf70/src/com/maddyhome/idea/vim/RegisterActions.java#L657).

Feel free to file a feature request about a proper emulation of the tag stack here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM.

Comment: Thank you!  Reported here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-3019